# Angular 2 html form validation

Tags: html, angular

I've created a form using html validations with Angular 2.

I want to to check the sate of the inputs (no empty, correct format, etc) when the user click to a certain button. At the moment I'm doing it as following:

```
    <form id="memberForm" #memberForm="ngForm" >
        <input
          type="text"
          id="MemberName"
          required
          name="MemberName"
          [(ngModel)]="newMember.name">        
    </form>
    <div  
        [ngClass]="{'button_disabledButton' : !memberForm?.valid}" 
        (click)="onSubmit(memberForm?.valid, memberForm);"> 
            <span>Next</span>
    </div>
```

With this, I'm only evaluating the input once clicked and focus out. How can I make it hapens when the user click in the "Next" element?

Comment: You can use [formGroup] to create some validations in the model, and use a button type submit and valid the the form <input type="button" value="Submit" [disabled]="!(Member.formGroup.valid)" />...something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should make getter/setter solution for your ngModel input.
In the .ts file in the appropriate class put this:

```
savedVar:string = '';
get variable(): string {
  return this.savedVar;
}
set variable(str: string) {
  this.savedVar = str;
  // do your validation
}
```

In template use ngModel=variable like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="variable">
```

Comment: That would work for just the validation, but I want to use the HTML one and set it as error once clicked, so this solution isn't what I'm looking for